# Optimized query to get IDs not present in other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery, query-optimization

I have three tables. T1 is the master and stores unique ID.
I want to get the IDs which are not present in t2 and t3 but are there in t1
I have written a query . Not sure if it is the correct and optimizes one. Need help to write the query in a better way than this as there is huge data in all the tables.

```
Select t1.ID 
  from t1 
 where ID not in ( 
                  Select distinct t2.ID from t2
                   Union
                  Select distinct t3.ID from t3
                 )
   and col2 ='A'
```

Comment: It's more about execution plan and it depends on your data distribution and cardinality of all 3 tables. Usually in case of all huge tables, it's better to get 2 `hash join anti`, so usually `not exists`, `not in` and `left join x where x.id is null` are better than set operators (set to join conversion was disabled by default, and it's enabled by default only on latest oracle versions)

Comment: Show us the results of the 3 following queries: 1. `Select count(*), count(distinct ID) from t1 where col2 ='A'` 2) `select count(*), count(distinct ID) from t2` 3) `select count(*), count(distinct ID) from t3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where
    col2 = 'A'
    and not exists(select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
    and not exists(select 1 from t3 where t3.id = t1.id)
```

This query should benefit the following indexes:

```
t1(col2, id)
t2(id)
t3(id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use only set operators:

```
SELECT t1.id
  FROM t1
 WHERE t1.col2 = 'A'
MINUS
(SELECT t2.id FROM t2
 UNION
 SELECT t3.id FROM t3
);
```